# Rename a subkey of an object with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JS object of the following structure:

```
let data = {
  Apples: {
    A: 2,
    B: 9
  },
  Oranges: {
    C: 4,
    D: 8
  },
  Bananas: {
    E: 3,
    F: 2
  },
  Peaches: {
    G: 8,
    H: 4
  },
  Pears: {
    I: 10,
    J: 10
  },
  Melons: {
    K: 4,
    L: 7
  }
};
```

I need to rename the subkey dynamically with JS.

**For example, I need to rename the key `A` into `New name`.
What is the best ES6-enabled way to do it?**

I tried to loop through the object using a simple `for` loop and generate a new object with a renamed key, but it's indeed not the most efficient way!

Comment: `data.Apples.newname=data.Apples.A; delete data.Apples.A;` you can put that into a dead-simple helper function if all the keys to be replaced are on the same depth in the object.

Comment: @ggorlen - It seems that OP clearly shows us that each fruit has its own properties.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. I'm not sure why a loop is even on the table if they're just renaming one property.

Comment: There is no ability to rename a property name.  You can create a new property name with the new name, assign it the desired value and then delete the previous property.

Comment: @dandavis your solution works perfectly, thanks!! I was clearly overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

I'm not generating a new object, but adding the new properties to the existing one and deleting the original ones.

```js
let data = {
  Apples: {
    A: 2,
    B: 9
  },
  Oranges: {
    C: 4,
    D: 8
  },
  Bananas: {
    E: 3,
    F: 2
  },
  Peaches: {
    G: 8,
    H: 4
  },
  Pears: {
    I: 10,
    J: 10
  },
  Melons: {
    K: 4,
    L: 7
  }
};

for (let key1 in data) {
  const e = data[key1];
  for (let key2 in e) {
    e["New Name for " + key2] = e[key2];
    delete e[key2];
  }
}

console.log(data);
```